# Regular expression not matching forward slash

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the following pattern:

```
LOCAL1*.CRIT /var/log/messages
```

with the regular expression:

```
(^LOCAL[0-9]|^[\\*])[.]([\\*]{1}|[a-zA-Z]*)\\s*(/[/a-zA-Z])
```

It seems to match everything except the path at the end. Any clue as to why this might be happening ?

Comment: * missing at the end, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this?

`(^LOCAL[0-9]\\*|^[\\*])[.]([\\*]{1}|[a-zA-Z]*)\\s*(/[/a-zA-Z]*)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing an asterisk at the end of the last group:

```
(^LOCAL[0-9]|^[\\*])[.]([\\*]{1}|[a-zA-Z]*)\\s*(/[/a-zA-Z]*)
                                                          ^ THIS
```

Otherwise you're only matching the first slash and one more character.

Also, there's something not quite right about your regex and the matching of `LOCAL1*`. In its present form the regex wouldn't match the last character (the `*`). This is easy to fix, but the correct fix depends on your requirements (is the `*` always there? is it optional? etc)

Comment: How will this match * following LOCAL1?